# How to get input from a calendar and print the date using JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

First of all, I'm very new to using JavaScript with HTML. Right now I have a calendar where a user can select the date they want. When selected I want the Date to print on the website for now. So if user selects 10/13/2019, I want the 10/13/2019 to print in my <p id="demo>. I want to print out the date right when the user clicks the date that they want. Any tips on how to do this? Here is what I have right now.

```
<html>

<head>
   <script src="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/dist/ej2.min.js"></script>
   <link href="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/material.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div style= text-align:center>
    <input id="datepicker"  onclick="print()" type="text">
    </div>

<p> Testing my Calender input </p>
<p id="demo"></p>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var datepicker = new ej.calendars.DatePicker({ width: "300px" });
    datepicker.appendTo('#datepicker');



    function print()
    {
      var input = document.getElementById("datepicker").value;

      document.getElementById('demo') = input;

    }

</script>



 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're almost right, just add `.textContent` or `.innerText` between  `document.getElementById('demo')` and `= input;`. Also, I recommend using `onchange` event instead of `onclick`...

Comment: document.getElementById('demo').innerText = input; 
I have changed it to this but I'm not getting any outputs on my website

Comment: Use onchange event instead of onclick... and I recommend avoiding inline listeners - but using them won't cause problems.

Comment: hmmm, I have changed it, but its still not showing up, I don't know if something is bugging out on my side.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you select a date the datePicker will update the input but updating an input programmatically doesn't trigger `change` event.

I see 2 options (there are probably more) to fixe that:

- The approximate solution: listen to `blur` event
- The (more) complicated solution: use an mutation observer on the body and find out when the datePicker is closed (element is removed)